# Using ElasticSearch's script_upsert to create a document

Tags: java, elasticsearch, upsert, elasticsearch-java-api

According to the official documentation [Update API - Upserts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_literal_scripted_upsert_literal) one can use `scripted_upsert` in order to handle update (for existing document) or insert (for new document) form within the script. The thing is they never show how the script should look to do that. The [Java - Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update.html) Doesn't have any information on the ScriptUpsert uses.

This is the code I'm using:

```
//My function to build and use the upsert
public void scriptedUpsert(String key, String parent, String scriptSource, Map<String, ? extends Object> parameters) {
    Script script = new Script(scriptSource, ScriptType.INLINE, null, parameters);
    UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest(index, type, key);
    request.scriptedUpsert(true);
    request.script(script);
    if (parent != null) {
        request.parent(parent);
    }
    this.bulkProcessor.add(request);
}

//A test call to validate the function
String scriptSource = "if (!ctx._source.hasProperty(\"numbers\")) {ctx._source.numbers=[]}";
Map<String, List<Integer>> parameters = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
numbers.add(100);
parameters.put("numbers", numbers);

bulk.scriptedUpsert("testUser", null, scriptSource, parameters);
```

And I'm getting the following exception when "testUser" documents doesn't exists:
`DocumentMissingException[[user][testUser]: document missing`

How can I make the scriptUpsert work from the Java code?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. This helped me out big time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how a `scripted_upsert` command should look like (and its script):

```
POST /sessions/session/1/_update
{
  "scripted_upsert": true,
  "script": {
    "inline": "if (ctx.op == \"create\") ctx._source.numbers = newNumbers; else ctx._source.numbers += updatedNumbers",
    "params": {
      "newNumbers": [1,2,3],
      "updatedNumbers": [55]
    }
  },
  "upsert": {}
}
```

If you call the above command and the index doesn't exist, it will create it, together with the `newNumbers` values in the new documents. If you call again the exact same command the `numbers` values will become `1,2,3,55`.

And in your case you are missing `"upsert": {}` part.

Comment: At the time I posted this @user1870400, `inline` didn't exist. This changed with time and with new versions changes. Your update is correct, but saying that the "answer is incorrect" is a bit stretched ;-).

Comment: If you paste the same exact payload into ES > 5 or 6 it fails even now.

Comment: 2 years ago there was no 5 or 6 version.

Comment: okies what I meant to say was even the above answer(after the update) still fails for version 5 and 6. And I understand the version of 5 and 6 still exists but it's better to modify the above answer to something that works. my 2 cents

Answer (score 2):

As Andrei suggested I was missing the upsert part, changing the function to:

```
public void scriptedUpsert(String key, String parent, String scriptSource, Map<String, ? extends Object> parameters) {
    Script script = new Script(scriptSource, ScriptType.INLINE, null, parameters);
    UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest(index, type, key);
    request.scriptedUpsert(true);
    request.script(script);
    request.upsert("{}"); // <--- The change
    if (parent != null) {
        request.parent(parent);
    }
    this.bulkProcessor.add(request);
}
```

Fix it.